# SciPy Windows 10 installation

Tags: python, windows, installation, scipy

I am a new Windows's user,

how can I install the scipy module (for python) from the command line (cmd) ?

```
thanks in advance
```

Comment: I highly recommend installing [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install). It will bring most of the essential Python packages along with it, including scipy.

Comment: thanks a lot my friend!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend downloading the wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and install via pip from the command line

Comment: via `pip install <name of the wheel file>.whl`